# MYSQL how to connect with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to insert data into the database, but the error. Can someone help me?
.............

CONEXAO.PHP

```
$banco = "*****";
$usuario = "*****";
$senha = "*****";
$hostname = "*****";

$conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$usuario,$senha); mysql_select_db($banco) or die( "Não foi possível conectar ao banco MySQL");

if (!$conn) {echo "Não foi possível conectar ao banco MySQL.
"; exit;}
else {echo "Parabéns!! A conexão ao banco de dados ocorreu normalmente!.
";}
mysql_close();
```

......................

CADASTRADO.PHP

```
include "conexao.php";
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM servicos";
$con = $conn ->query($consulta) or die ($conn->error); (((error in this line)))
```

...............

MSG ERROR

```
Parabéns!! A conexão ao banco de dados ocorreu normalmente!. (CONECTION OK)

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on resource in /var/www/html/paranalocal.com.br/web/servicos.php on line 4
```

Comment: You should probably remove that password...

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli_` with `mysql_`. [The latter has been removed from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: `mysql_*` functions don't work like that. They're also outdated. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Not to mention you close the connection as soon as you open it

Comment: I've edited out the user/pass but you still need to change it **immediately**.

Answer (score 0):

To use mysqli functions you need to create a connection to the database using [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php).

Replace `mysql_connect` with the following:

```
$conn = new mysqli($hostname , $usuario, $senha, $banco);
```

Comment: If you look a bit closer, OP is also trying to use `$conn->error`, so assume mysqli over pdo.

Comment: My bad, thanks for noticing. I updated the answer.